# In which file should it be best to put full debugging commands such as set -x (and also && complete -r)?

Tags: bash, debugging

CentOS on a shared website hosting environment (I don't know the version) with Bash 5.0.17(1).

I use `set -x` to get maximal trace which often helps me handle errors; I normally use this command combination:

```
set -x && complete -r
```

`complete -r` hides some very messy output I never found useful.

I want that the command combination will always be on, in all sessions but I am not sure in which file it is best to put it, perhaps:

- `.bashrc`
- `.profile`
- `.bash_profile`
- Possible similar files (files which allow to commands to run after boot, at least for some users)

Comment: You probably only need to add it to `~/.profile` and nowhere else, but the details depend on your operating system. Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using and, if Linux, which distribution.

Comment: @terdon thanks ; edited.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than turning on debugging for all your scripts (and being buried in more debugging info than you can handle),

1. Create a directory, say `$HOME/.user-debug`.
2. In each script you want to debug:

   ```
   # get the name of this script
   me=${0##*/}
   if [[ "$HOME/.user-debug/$me" ]] ; then
         source "$HOME/.user-debug/$me"
   fi
   ```

and put your debugging in the files in `$HOME/.user-debug/scriptname`.

That way, you can turn off debugging by removing the file in `$HOME/.user-debug/scriptname`.